# ¿Como ejecutar 2 querys en una misma conexión?

Tags: c#, sql-server, consola

Buen día.

Realizo una implementación en C#, en el cual deberá leer los datos un archivo de texto (esta parte ya la tengo).
Tengo una conexión a una base de datos donde guardo los errores, ahora intento guardar las excepciones en esta base, el detalle esta en que tengo que ejecutar dos consultas pero me arroja el mensaje "Ya hay un DataReader abierto asociado a este Command, debe cerrarlo primero." ya he investigado, pero no veo la manera de solucionarlo.
Anexo el codigo que manejo.

```
        #region Producto
    //Metodo con arreglo, asigna los datos de cada linea de producto
    public static Productos[] Producto(string startFolder)
    {
        string fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        List<string> Datos = LeerArchvioTXT(startFolder);

        Productos[] lineas = new Productos[Datos.Count - 2];
        //FOR para leer los datos de los productos linea por linea
        for (int a = 2; a < Datos.Count; a++)
        {
            try
            {
                char separador = '|';
                string[] DatosCol;
                DatosCol = Datos[a].Split(separador);
                lineas[a - 2].Codigo = DatosCol[2];
                //lineas[a - 2].Observaciones = DatosCol[6]; //Referencia
                lineas[a - 2].Observaciones = DatosCol[6]; //Observaciones
                lineas[a - 2].Cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[7]); //Cantidad
                lineas[a - 2].Precio = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[8]); //Precio
                //lineas[a - 2].Impuesto1 = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[4]);//impuesto1
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                conexionbd conexionbd = new conexionbd();
                string sCon = conexionbd.CadenaConexion();

                string sel1 = "select RutaEntrada from Rutas_Datos";
                string sel2 = "Insert into Prueba(ID_Doc, Detalle_Error, Fecha) values (@ID_Doc, @detalle, @fecha)";

                
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sCon))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sel1, con);
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sel2, con);
                    SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;

                    while (reader1.Read())
                    {
                        string startFold = reader1["RutaEntrada"].ToString();
                        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFold);

                        IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                        
                        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileList)
                        {
                            
                            if (dir.Exists)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Doc", fi.Name.ToString());
                                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detalle", ex.Message);
                                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fecha.ToString());

                                    dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
                                }
                                catch (SqlException exS)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(exS.Message);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }con.Close();
                } 
            }
        }
        return lineas;
    }
    #endregion
```

Explico un poco, el primer query lo ejecuto para tomar la ruta de entrada de los archivos de texto, y el segundo query es para insertar la excepción a la base. Si la ruta la colo manual, es decir, hago un string con la ruta y solo ejecuto el query de Insert, funciona correctamente, pero si quiero ejecutar ambos querys me manda el error.
La ruta la estoy mandando a llamar ya que se requiere guardar en la base el nombre del archivo que mando la excepción.
Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia para mejorar es bienvenida. 
Me disculpo de antemano si pregunto demasiado, pero estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: un ejemplo de recibir dos reader o mas.
segui este enlace:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448899/how-to-read-multiple-resultset-from-sqldatareader

Answer (score 2):

Esto se puede resolver fácilmente permitiendo el uso de multiples result sets activos (MARS) definiendo `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` en tu "connectionString" :

ejemplo:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" +
    "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;" +  
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

Revisa:

[Enabling Multiple Active Result Sets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets)

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, agradezco tu respuesta, me ha sido de ayuda, sin embargo ahora me arroja el mensaje "The variable "@archivo" name has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure." , y hace el proceso correcto, o sea, guarda la excepción en la base y  pasa a leer el siguiente archivo.

Comment: Me parece que el problema es que solo defines un SqlDataReader : SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sel1, con);
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sel2, con);
                    SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader(); deberías agregar otro                     SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Agradezco las respuestas, he solucionado el detalle, para el error "The variable @archivo" solo debía cerrar el Reader1.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo el *flujo* de tu código, diría que el error está en esta parte:

```
SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```

Ya que creas dos `SqlDataReader` asociados al `cmd1`, pero sospecho que tu intención era uno solo, para la única sentencia `select` que tienes, por lo que habría que quitar la segunda línea y dejar solo la primera:

```
SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```